# Pass AWS config to imported module

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to unit test a JS AWS Lambda by running it locally. To emulate the Lambda environment I am assuming the same role as the Lambda would have with AWS.config.credentials and then simply calling the Lambda function that I imported with require.

This works if I copy and paste the Lambda function to the test file but if I import it then it seems the function runs with a clean AWS.config which doesn't have my configuration. I could change the way the Lambda module imports AWS (make it global or do something else) in order to get the config from the test but I would prefer to keep the file exactly as it should be for uploading to Lambda.

In AWS Lambda the AWS credentials are somehow preconfigured without the module having to do anything and I would like to emulate that functionality. How can this be done in Node?

EDIT:
You can run any example function in AWS Lambda. For example just the following code simply works when run in proper AWS Lambda.

```js
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
dynamo.query(...)
```

To run this locally you have to precede this code with the following:

```js
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'}); 
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials();
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.TemporaryCredentials({
  RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/TemporaryCredentials',
});
```

The problem is that running this config step in the unit test file does not make the config available to an imported lambda function and does therefore not emulate the environment properly.

Comment: How are they somehow preconfigured? Could you show us the relevant code in lambda?

Comment: I don't know if it is preconfigured in their implementation but if you access anything from aws-sdk while running in the real Lambda environment you simply have the credentials of the role of the lambda without any code to get them. The only way I can think of to emulate this is by configuring the AWS object.

Comment: They must be set somewhere. Could you show us the code?

Comment: Ok I have added example code.

Comment: If it's a `unit` test, you should be mocking it so you don't need that config anymore. I think what you mean is an `integration` test.

Comment: @dashmug I guess that's true, a true unit test should technically probably use a mocked up version of AWS instead of really connecting to it but that sounds pretty difficult. I think the term is probably sufficient in the context of an AWS lambda though but not necessarily the function inside it.

Comment: Can you run your code locally? If you can run it locally, you should be able to run the tests locally as well without those config lines.

Comment: @dashmug this specific function doesn't really have any logic other than in the way it interfaces with AWS services so testing it without something that perfectly emulates my AWS environment would be useless. It would be interesting if Amazon made an AWS mocking tool though.

Comment: @Gerharddc, that's what I mean by running it locally. Can you run it locally and still be able to interface with your AWS resources (RDS, S3, etc)?

Comment: @dashmug yes I can as long as I get the aws-sdk to assume the correct role. My problem here is that I am struggling to get that done without changing the lambda file in any way, i.e. emulate the real lambda environment. If I add the credentials code at the top though it runs perfectly on my local machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154254/discussion-between-dashmug-and-gerharddc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution using [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/). For sure you can adapt it to other testing frameworks. I just think it's easier in `jest`.

Basically, you create a mock of the `aws-sdk` module that returns the actual `aws-sdk` module **AND** your own modifications.

```
// __mocks__/aws-sdk.js (Jest automocks this module if you follow this convention)
'use strict';

const AWS = require('AWS');


// Make your own modifications
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'}); 
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials();
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.TemporaryCredentials({
  RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/TemporaryCredentials',
});


//export modified module
module.exports = AWS
```

With this, when your lambda requires `aws-sdk`, it loads this module instead. And with it comes the actual `aws-sdk` module AND your additional config.

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html#content

Comment: I am using jest and this might actually work even better than the process.env option, I'll check if it works

Answer (score 1):

Before you run your test, you need to call STS.AssumeRole and obtain the temporary credentials, and put them in the environment.  That is how Lambda appears to do it.  The service calls AssumeRole, gets the temporary credentials, and puts them in a place where the SDK expects them to be.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

If you examine `process.env` in a running Lambda function, you'll see that these variables are set.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-environment.html

Note that when I say "before you run your test," I mean before you start it at all -- not at the top of the code.

Note also that the access key and secret are not those from your IAM credentials.  Calling AssumeRole provides you with a temporary key, temporary secret, and temporary token.

Comment: Ok but I guess these credentials are temporary and will need to be recaptured quite regularly? Is there no way to set the environment in one js file before requiring another?

Comment: It appears that assuming a role doesn't actually populate accessKeyId and sessionToken on the AWS.Config and it doesn't have a readable field for AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY either.

Comment: See [`assumeRole`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html#assumeRole-property).  The credentials can have a lifetime of up to an hour.  You need to take these values and populate them into environment variables.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly if I set process.env before requiring the module.